# Rays and lenses in a viewfinder

Tags: optics, lenses

An electronic camera viewfinder has a LCD screen and a combination of lenses. When looking into the viewfinder the image looks much bigger than the actual LCD though. In fact when looking from a bit further back one can only see a tiny middle part of the LCD.

[image]

I am wondering what kind of lenses create this projection when looking into the viewfinder. I am especially struggling to draw the rays.

It would be great if someone could explain or point me to another source for an explanation. My search terms have failed me so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lens through which you look at the viewfinder screen basically is the same thing as a magnifying glass.

I did a search for pages that explain how a magnifying glass works, and I was surprised by how little information on that subject is out there. The best I could find was this:

https://www.quora.com/Why-are-convex-lenses-called-magnifying-glass

The diagram attempts to show how, when you use a magnifier to look at a small object that is very close to your eye, the lens bends the rays so that they seem to come from a larger object that is further away.

The picture only shows two rays, both coming from one point on the object. In reality, there are infinitely many rays coming from infinitely many points, and the lens does the same thing for all of them.

Comment: At least it's not just me not finding the right information on this :) But that diagram is pretty good. I just tried putting a convex lens up close to the eye and indeed it seems to be that simple. A proper viewfinder will have a more complex aspherical setup - but I think this answered the question good enough. Thanks!